# Spring boot post redirect return 302 status

Tags: spring-boot, redirect, spring-security

I want to redirect to main page after successful registration. Registration is successful but the redirect process is not successful.Again it returns to the login page and post method returns with 302 status.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/bireysel/kaydet" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveBireyselKullanici(@Valid
        @ModelAttribute("kullaniciKayitModel") KullaniciKayitModel kullaniciKayitModel,
        Model model,
        BindingResult bindingResult,
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    ErrorDetail errorDetail = null;

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "yeniKayit";
    }

    kullaniciKayitModel.setBireyselKurumsal(BireyselKurumsalTypeEnum.BIREYSEL);

    errorDetail = registerService.hesapOlustur(kullaniciKayitModel);

    if(errorDetail == null) {
        registerService.authenticateUserAndSetSession(kullaniciKayitModel, request);
        model.addAttribute("welcomeMessage", "Hoş geldiniz");
        return "redirect:/anasayfa";
    }else {
        model.addAttribute("hataMesaj", "Kayıt esnasında hata meydana geldi!");
        return "yeniKayit";
    }

}
```

My security config is below :

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username,password,enabled from toptansepetim.users WHERE username=? ")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT username,role from toptansepetim.user_roles where username=?");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new RequestMatcher() {
        private Pattern allowedMethods = Pattern.compile("^(GET|POST)$");
        private RegexRequestMatcher apiMatcher = new RegexRequestMatcher("", null);

        @Override
        public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
            if (allowedMethods.matcher(request.getMethod()).matches())
                return false;

            if (apiMatcher.matches(request))
                return false;

            return true;
        }
    });

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**","/js/**","/fonts/**","/images/**", "/yeniKayit","/anasayfa","/bireysel/kaydet","/rest/kullanici/mevcut","/api/ililce/il/liste","/api/ililce/ilce/liste","/kullanici/bireysel/kaydet","/exceptions/**", "/home", "/anasayfa")
            .permitAll().antMatchers()
            .access("hasRole('" + RolTypeEnum.NORMAUL_USER.getValue() + "')").anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/anasayfa").permitAll().usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password").and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll().and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/exceptions/403").and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository());

}

@Override
@Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)    
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

also my login method in successfull registration is below

```
  public void authenticateUserAndSetSession(KullaniciKayitModel 
  model,HttpServletRequest request) {
    String username = model.getUsername();
    String password = model.getPassword();

     UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
     authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
     Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authToken);
     SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
}
```

What is the reason of 302 status redirect in Spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The problem's reason is PassworEncoder. You must send the password with decode for authanticate.